# Angular uigrid - remove subgrid's left margin spacing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the Angular [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial) and Angular (v1.4). I can display a simple table fine but when it comes to nested tables
To see an example of the code - go to http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid, then click on the "Edit in Plunkr" link on the right about halfway down. In this example, when you click on a row you'll see the subgrid. That's fine but for this subgrid I'd like to remove the whitespace to the left subgrid's ID column and also ensure the subgrid's columns line up the the parent columns.

Does anyone know how I can do this ?

Any thoughts/guidance would be great.
Thanks - Ro

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview is not your plunker .. please update it

Comment: I updated the content of my post to show how to access the running code example by clicking on the "Edit in Plunkr" link off the uigrid tutorial page.Trusting that is ok.